# How do I get the MySQL affected rows using the Magento resource?

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I am using following update query,

```
$db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

$query = UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_decimal` val SET val.value = '11' 
WHERE val.attribute_id = 75 AND 
val.entity_id = (select cv.entity_id from `catalog_product_entity` as cv where cv.sku = '25' limit 1)

$afected = $db->query($query);
```

How could I get the affected rows count from the above query?. I have already looked on the
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10623/how-do-i-get-the-mysql-affected-rows-using-the-magento-resource - but those not works for me.

Kindly advice me on the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$db->exec($query);` instead of `$db->query($query);`. It returns the number of affected rows.